# Why can't I skip LWC namespaces in namesspaced scratch org

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components, managed-package, isv

I have an LWC component as part of a managed package. To support Classic its also embedded inside VF page using a Lightning App(Aura):

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account">

    <apex:includeLightning/>
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:myComponent", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:myComponent",
                { 
                    ...
                },
                "lightning"
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

The component loads perfectly in my **namespaced scratch org** but once I install the package to a (QA) org the component does not render and instead displays a GACK error Error ID: 2051565161-29181 (-293734425).

Checking my browser console reveals this exception:

```
{
    "stack": "Error: Blocked a frame with origin https://my-scratch-domain.ap5.visual.force.com from accessing a cross-origin frame.↵    at injectIntoContentWindow (<anonymous>:26:34)↵    at HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindowDesc.get [as contentWindow] (<anonymous>:60:7)↵    at l (https://my-scratch-domain.ap5.visual.force.com/jslibrary/1558397236222/sfdc/SfdcSessionBase208.js:30:193)",
    "code": 18,
    "name": "SecurityError",
    "message": "Blocked a frame with origin https://my-scratch-domain.ap5.visual.force.com from accessing a cross-origin frame."
}
```

When I changed the code in VF page to use `namespace:AppName` and `namespace:componentName` it magically fixed the error

Is this an expected behavior? Reading the documentation I think I could omit the use of namespaces inside a packaging or or a namespaced scratch org:

> To reference this app on your page, use the following JavaScript code,
>   where theNamespace is the namespace prefix for the app. That is,
>   either your org’s namespace, or the namespace of the managed package
>   that provides the app.
>
> $Lightning.use("theNamespace:lcvfTest", function() {}); If the app is
>   defined in your org (that is, not in a managed package), you can use
>   the default “c” namespace instead, as shown in the next example. If
>   your org doesn’t have a namespace defined, you must use the default
>   namespace.